# What is the correct encoding type for FormData?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that for my POST requests, I had to use:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

or there would be an error.

However, when sending a FormData Object as my only data, I have no requestHeaders set and things work fine.

I found this strange that one requires a header and one does not.  Just wanted to verify.

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) state that

```
// xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

is used implicitly.  I.E. don't actually set this header as it is used by default for form data.

Setting it actually causes an error.  That's right setting it according to the documentation will break your code.

From the docs:

> It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set
>   to "multipart/form-data".

Is there any formal documentation that describes how to use this FormData, i.e. how to use it with ajax correctly.

I have got it working using trial and error but I wanted a solid reference, so I'm more confident in my code.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: To have an answer, one must first have a question...

Comment: I think the answer is that the only way to set the encoding for a `FormData` is to construct it from an existing form, in which case it picks up the form's `enctype`. I can't find any docs for this either. If you've found the answer, please post it.

Answer (score -1):

The correct encoding type is whatever encoding you're using for your form data. The purpose of the header is to tell the server host to interpret the data you're sending.

Whether this matters depends on how the server application processes the data. If it reads the raw input, the header is irrelevant. But if it makes use of form processing provided by a library or runtime environment, such as PHP filling in `$_POST`, the form data must be encoded and the header must match the encoding.